# Animação de imagem com efeito pulse e brilho em css

Tags: css3, css-animations

É possível apenas com css fazer uma imagem ficar pulsando e passando um efeito com brilho?

Comment: Sim é claro que é possível...

Comment: Tem como colocar um exemplo de como seria o efeito de brilho?

Comment: Você já tentou fazer alguma coisa? Poste o que conseguiu até aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Modificando um pouco o exemplo do miguel é possível obter o seguinte resultado...

```css
.pulse {
  animation: pulse 0.7s infinite;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  margin-top: 50px;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(200%);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    filter: brightness(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    filter: brightness(200%);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQORaH2BF3ZzUy2ATj866BszLShnoe2cRbjc-WQauazk5iThjC-4w" class="pulse">
```

Infelizmente o suporte para filtros ainda é baixo para os navegadores, caso seu alvo seja IE, não recomendo usar.

Comment: Bom trabalho Felipe

Comment: Em adição ao "infelizmente o suporte para filtros ainda é baixo", veja [Can I use?](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)